# Who was the reporter to whom Donald Trump said "You're fake news"?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, fake-news

In today's press conference while Donald Trump was taking questions he told one reporter;

> “No, not you, your organization is terrible. Quiet. Quiet,” he said. As the reporter continued trying to ask a question, talking over another reporter, Mr. Trump continued: “Don’t be rude. Don’t be rude. Don’t. Be. Rude. I’m not going to give you a question. You are fake news.”

Source: [CBS](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/donald-trump-holds-first-post-election-press-conference-live-updates/)

Who was this reporter and what organization did he work for?

Comment: This question could be improved by:  1.) Adding a reference to the event you are talking about (some readers won't know about this event), 2.) Writing the entire question in the body, rather than spacing it between the title and body, and 3.) Adding any other details that may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks Indigochild for the advice and Skooba for the edit. I will keep these things in mind in the future; I am brand new to stack exchange.

Comment: @user11332 Welcome to the SE network. I am new to this particular stack myself!

Comment: @user11332 - No problem, we were all new once. I added a link to the news article and I changed my downvote to an upvote.  One last note - typically we leave questions open a bit longer. Once a question is closed answers usually stop, and we like to see lots of good answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reporter was [Jim Acosta](http://www.cnn.com/videos/politics/2017/01/11/donald-trump-jim-acosta-cnn-fake-news.cnn)

> **[A CNN reporter](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/donald-trump-holds-first-post-election-press-conference-live-updates/)** in the audience attempted to ask a follow-up question, but Mr. Trump repeatedly shut him down.
>
> “No, not you, your organization is terrible. Quiet. Quiet,” he said. As the reporter continued trying to ask a question, talking over another reporter, Mr. Trump continued: “Don’t be rude. Don’t be rude. Don’t. Be. Rude. I’m not going to give you a question. You are fake news.”

The clip from the conference can be seen here, starting at about 1:06:00,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUyAk0bYps0

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what the "you are fake news" reference means and specifically why CNN reporter was called that.

Comment: @user4012 considering the full "answer", I am not sure the fake news comment was meant to be very meaningful.